# Can you run code before creating a type provider? (F#)

Tags: f#, type-providers

Say:

```
let x = // some operation
type t = SomeTypeProvider<x>
```

Is this valid?

Comment: 1. yes, you can. 2. you probably mean `type t = SomeTypeProvider<x>`.

Comment: thanks, I've corrected that mistake

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled though, what exactly is the issue you are facing? You can place a type provider anywhere in your code, i.e. after doing something unrelated or defining some other types.

Comment: As long as `x` is constant, yes, you can.

Comment: @CaringDev yeah, in my case `x` is not a constant, but a ssh client creation

Comment: Let me clarify this as you got all kinds of replies, possibly because the question is suffficiently vague for everyone to read into whatever they want. You can run any code before creating a type provider. Of course you cannot access the stuff inside the type provider before you create, but that should be obvious. In your case you can  certainly create an ssh client before instantiating the type provider. Then you can specify the parameters as [<Literal>] If your question means, can you specify the connection string dynamically, then no, and the answer below applies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**.

Since the types must be generated at compile-time, the parameter to the type provider needs to be a constant.

In other words, the code you marked `// some operation` can evaluate to a literal, but cannot be a value returned by a runnable function:

```
let arg = "foo"
type t = SomeTypeProvider<arg> // okay

let [<Literal>] arg = """{"name":"foo","value":42}"""
type t = SomeTypeProvider<arg> // okay

let arg = x.ToString()
type t = SomeTypeProvider<arg> // Boom! arg is not a Literal
```

---

It depends on your application, but one of the most common cases is the following:

You have a database-related Type Provider, and the connection string needs to be retrieved in runtime, from some sort of config file or something. So a developer mistakenly thinks they need a runnable code to retrieve the connection string first and then pass it to the Type Provider.

The correct approach is the following:

Keep **two databases**: one locally stored in a constant location (just for schema), and another one for the runtime purposes.
Pass the first one (a constant!) to your Type Provider. Don't worry about the hardcoded paths; it is only used for schema retrieval.

```
// Use a fixed sample file for schema generation only
type MyCSVData = CsvProvider<"dummy.csv">

// Load the actual data at runtime
let data = MyCSVData.Load(RetrieveFileNameFromConfig())
```